# Display WordPress posts by ID on external website?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I know how to pull the last 3 posts from a blog and display them on an external website, but is it possible to specify post ID(s) and have those posts show on an external site?  For example, if I want to show posts 5, 12, and 15 on the homepage of my external site?

Comment: Yep, I believe the REST API can do that. Check its documentation for more details.

Comment: Looks like the REST API is what I needed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$url = 'YOUR_BLOG_URL';

// Get latest 3 posts
$latestPosts = file_get_contents($url . '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?orderby=date&order=desc&per_page=3');

// Get 3 specific posts by ID
$postIds = array(5, 12, 15);
$specificPosts = file_get_contents($url . '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?orderby=date&order=desc&include=' . implode(',', $postIds));
```

Here's a link to the REST API documentation for a full list of arguments:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you.